# How to pass dynamic param to function called through injectJavaScript in react-native-webview

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I am using react-native-webview for loading url in webview. I just want to call a function of frontend from native app using webview for some functionality.

`this.webView.ref.injectJavaScript('window.chatComponentService.openChat()')`

It works fine with static param

`this.webView.ref.injectJavaScript('window.chatComponentService.openChat("anyValue")')`

But what if i want to pass dynamic value like:

`this.webView.ref.injectJavaScript('window.chatComponentService.openChat(&{someParam})')`

What should i do to pass dynamic param here in function call?

Answer (score 2):

You may JSON.stringify the params before sending it. What I usually do is

```js
const message = JSON.stringify({
    x: 'value1',
    y: 'value2',
    z: 'value3'
});

this.webView.ref.injectJavaScript(`window.chatComponentService.openChat(${message})`)
```

Comment: I have tried this as well but not working and through an warning with "Error evaluating injected.JavaScript"

Comment: What worked here is: this.webView.ref.injectJavaScript('window.chatComponentService.openChat(' + someParam + ')')
If someParam is not a string.